# Laravel boolean returns "1"/"0" instead of true/false in query

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have a query that returns a boolean field (by the way, I'm on an SQL Server) on my REST API developed with Laravel and a few days ago it was returning the value as true/false, but now it returns that boolean value as String: "1"/"0".

Any idea on what could it be?

I tried using casting on my Model like this:

```
 protected $casts = [
    'status' => 'boolean',
 ];
```

This is my query:

```
return DB::table('dbo.visits as V')
        ->leftJoin('dbo.reports AS R', 'R.id_visit', '=', 'V.id')
        ->select('R.id','R.status'); // status is the boolean
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What data type are you storing it as, `bit`?

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have a `boolean` data type, so you can't have a query that returns one. If you want to store the values `TRUE`/`FALSE` you would have to use a `varchar(5)` and the values `'true'` and `'false'`. Most people, however, use a `bit`, which allows the values `0` and `1` (and `NULL`), however, it does not *act* like a boolean.

Comment: Yes, it's stored as a bit

Comment: *"Yes, it's stored as a bit "* Well that's why you're getting `0` or `1`; because that's the value of the column. A `bit` isn't a `boolean`. The 2 are different data types.

Comment: Consider to use Eloquent, where you can cast the attribute to boolean https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ I forgot to mention that I've already tried that but didn't work

Comment: I think you need to use Eloquent model for cast to work. Right now you are using raw query to select directly from table.

Comment: Oh, yes, you have to perform the query by your eloquent Model, the cast will not work by DB Query Builder. Also, you can try with an accesor. Something like `public function getStatusAttribute($value) { $value ? true : false; }`

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ wouldn't the same problem occur? Will it work on DB query?

Comment: @user3532758 Yes, for the two options I mentioned, the query should be done from the Eloquent Model. I think the cast should work and it is the specific tool for that. I only mentioned the accessor because OP mentioned that cast doesn't work.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When you're defining the following:

```
protected $casts = [
  'status' => 'boolean',
];
```

You're defining it on the model. However, when you initiate your query using `DB::table()`, **you're not using the model**, so the binding doesn't actually apply. Initiate your query using your model:

```
return Visit::leftJoin('dbo.reports AS R', 'R.id_visit', '=', 'dbo.visits.id')
->select('R.id','R.status'); // status is the boolean
```

Note: Had to adjust query to `dbo.visits.id` from `V.id` due to aliasing not being available at that point.

Answer (score 2):

Defining casts is working when you are using Eloquent models. In code you provided you use query builder and then Eloquent models are not used at all, so no casts are done.

Answer (score 0):

What you would like to do is add this function to your model. Every time you use your model to retrieve data, this function matching the attribute name will be called to convert your raw data from the database to your desired format.

```
public function getStatusAttribute($value)
{
        return $value ? 'Yes' : 'No';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Eloquent: API Resources

```
/*Controller*/
$sel_visit= Visit::leftJoin('dbo.reports AS R', 'R.id_visit', '=', 'dbo.visits.id')->select('R.id','R.status')->get(); // status is the boolean
VisitResource::collection($sel_visit);
```

Then using a API Resources

```
public function toArray($request)
    {

        if($this->status==1) { $status=true;} else {$status=false;}
        
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'status' => $status
        ];
    }
```